# Can not push viewcontroller again in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I have 3 ViewController, flow: rootviewcontroller is view1 , when i click on "Start"button in view1, it push view2 and then click on "Status" button in view2, it push view3 . In view3 has uitabbarcontroller and inside tabbarcontroller has 2 UINavigationController . My problem is : When click on "Logout"button in UINavigationController in tabbarcontroller, i call back view2. But when view2 appear, I click on "Status"button, it can not push view3.
Code for created UItabbarcontroller

```
self.tab=[[UITabBarController alloc]init];
CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
if (screenBounds.size.height == 568)
{
    // code for 4-inch screen
    //  LoginButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 518, 80, 49);
    self.tab.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,320,568);
}
else if (screenBounds.size.height == 1024)
{
    //code for ipad

}
else  if (screenBounds.size.height == 480)
{
    // code for 3.5-inch screen
    //  LoginButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 430, 80, 49);
    self.tab.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,320,480);
}

// FirstViewController
UploadTab *uploadview=[[UploadTab alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *uploadTabItem = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: uploadview] autorelease];
uploadview.title=@"Uploading";
uploadview.tabBarItem.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Uploading.png"];
self.title = @"FirstViewControllerTitle";

//SecondViewController
ConvertTab *convertView=[[ConvertTab alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *convertTabItem = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: convertView] autorelease];
convertView.title=@"Convert";
convertView.tabBarItem.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Convert.png"];

//ThirdViewController
CompletedTab *completedView=[[CompletedTab alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *completedTabItem = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: completedView] autorelease];
completedView.title=@"Completed";
completedView.tabBarItem.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Completed.png"];
UIBarButtonItem * LogoutItem= [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Logout.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(logout)];

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = LogoutItem;
self.tab.viewControllers=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:uploadTabItem,convertTabItem, completedTabItem, nil];

[self.view insertSubview:self.tab.view belowSubview: uploadview.view];
[self presentModalViewController:self.tab animated:NO];
```

I use below code to call back view2:

```
    - (void) handleBack:(id)sender
{
    ChooseViewController *chooseview = [[ChooseViewController alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:chooseview animated:NO];
    [chooseview release];

}
```

I used `[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:loginView animated:YES];`
. I thinks it made view2 can not push view3.
Do you have any suggestions ? Thanks a lot

Comment: When you say "it can not push view3", what happens instead? Please tell us what happens in your UI and what (if anything) is printed to Xcode's debug console.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this might be useful:

```
NSArray *viewControllers = [[self navigationController] viewControllers];  
    for (int i = 0; i < [viewContrlls count]; i++){  
        id obj = [viewControllers objectAtIndex:i];  
        if ([obj isKindOfClass:[yourViewControllername class]]){  
            [[self navigationController] popToViewController:obj animated:YES];  
            return;
        }
    }
```

using this you can come back to any specific view.